# Check type from table between dates MySQL,php

Tags: php, mysql

I have table as seen below:

```
ID, Date, Type 
1,  2015-1-1,  2 
2,  2015-5-1,  5 
3,  2015-8-10,  4


(before 2015-1-1 .... type = default  
2015-1-1 <= Date < 2015-5-1 .... type = 2  
2015-5-1 <= Date < 2015-8-10 .... type = 5  
since 2015-8-10 .... type = 4)
```

I would like simply check which type is for any `$date`.

I tryed:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM smlouvy  
        WHERE Date < '".$date."'  
        ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1";

$result = MySQL_Query($sql);  
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {
    $type = 'default';
}
else {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$type = $row["Type"];
}
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I want return Type for date get_type($date)

Comment: But you already have column `type` , Just put it in your select query

Comment: if you need type you want to just check if(Date < 2015-1-1){$type = "default"} like this you will identify type for date

Comment: ? for exampe: if date = 2016-1-1 .. type = 4

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
select ID,date, 
          case  `date`
          when `date`<='2015-11-01' then 4
          when `date`>='2015-11-01' then 5
          else 1 end as `type` 
 from tbl;
```

Note: This is just an example,you may need to modify the conditions as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution (**if `Date` column matches within a certain range**):

```
$dateFrom = '2015-5-1';
$dateTo = '2015-8-10';

// exemplary query
$query = "SELECT type FROM table_name
          WHERE $dateFrom <= Date < $dateTo 
          ORDER BY Date ASC LIMIT 1 ";
// it will return the type of lower date column from range (type = 5)
```

Comment: @DaveMX, and how would you get `type` = 2 for `$date = 2015-3-1` ?